# wp function get_comments() VS WP_Comment_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

simple question on better method- get_comments() VS WP_Comment_Query:

Which is a better method to echo out comment content (as far as speed, security)?

in both cases:

```
$args = array(
'meta_value' => 'tagline111'
);
```

This:

```
$comments = get_comments( $args );
foreach( $comments as $comment ) }
   echo $comment->comment_content;
}
```

OR

```
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
    echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_comments()` uses `WP_Comment_Query`.

The function definition for `get_comments()` is in /wp-includes/comment.php:

```
function get_comments( $args = '' ) {
    $query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    return $query->query( $args );
}
```